# migrating AWS instances to GCP with new velostrata GCP migrate 4.11

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I am willing to migrate Ec2 instances from AWS to Google Cloud using GCP's internal tool migrate last version v4.11( previously Velostrata).
I have done all the setup on both sides and everything seems to be communicating fine, helper vms are automatically created on AWS and GCP during migrations. 
The doubt that I have is that when I configure the module on AWS side (cloudformation stack for Iam credentials ...) all is fine, the migrate console talks to AWS via the credentials, but it only proposes to select AWS Frankfurt and AWS London datacenters in Europe and not AWS Paris and AWS Milan.
Unluckily my VMs are in AWS Paris Dc. even though I have set the VPN tunnel between GCP and Paris AWS region, when I launch a runbook creation, only the test VMs located in AWS London are detected and not the ones in AWS Paris (yes I have set the same networks tags on all London and Paris Vms).
 So that makes me think that GCP migrate talks to AWS via the API and the VPN is for the transfer traffic which makes sense. Then I don't understand why some AWS regions are not represented in the list of AWS dc to migrate from in Velostrata tool.

Once I move the VPN to AWS London region, the migration process gets better and vms are moved from London Aws datacenter to GCP. 
I am wondering why GCP migrate is only limited to certain AWS regions (like London and Frankfurt in Europe). Nothing is in the Google docs on that matter . 
 Does anybody has had this experience ? How could you resolve it ? Do I need to migrate my vms inside AWS from AWS Paris to AWS London and then afterwards to GCP ?

Answer (score 0):

There is currently no known limitations to migrate from any AWS region to GCP region , however GCP Paris region is not provisioned yet and currently under the pipeline , please check the [documentation-1](https://cloud.google.com/about/locations#regions) for the details.

Please also check the [documentation-2](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/regions-zones) for the    available and announced regions and zones as well.

As per my knowledge there is no restrictions to migrate instance from any of the available AWS regions to any available GCP regions , however if you are having any issues then I would recommend to open an Issue tracker by following the [documentation-3](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers) and share your information for investigation and troubleshooting purposes.

Comment: Hi. thanks for looking into this, but the region I am talking about is AWS Paris and not GCP paris .The issue is that the velostrata tool does not permit me to migrate instances located in AWS Paris region but it does for London region instances. it is not a matter of rights or network access and routes, it's just that the list displayed in velostrata tool just permits to select AWS London or Frankfurt and not AWS Paris or Milan region

Comment: Your issue seems like require an investigation and review of your process/steps and also need to acquire more information . It is therefore suggested to open an Issue tracker by following the [documentation-3](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers) and share your information for investigation and troubleshooting purposes.    Please also make sure to follow the proper guideline and steps while performing migration from AWS as mentioned in the [documentation-2](https://cloud.google.com/migrate/compute-engine/docs/4.2/how-to).